# Reflecting on a Discriminated Union

Tags: c#, f#

I am getting a bunch of objects from an F# assembly, which I am then reflecting over to discover their value.

(To be precise I have a parser using fsYacc. I am then trying to display the results of the parse in a TreeView.)

One of the possible objects returned is this Discriminated union :

```
type op = Eq | Gt | Ge | Lt | Le
```

An object of this type will have a value, say `Ge`.

Is there any way using reflection that I can determine that an object is a Discriminated union, and hence take steps to determine its value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To determine if it is a disriminated union - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353623.aspx - `FSharpType.IsUnion`

To get value use `Reflection.UnionCaseInfo` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370473.aspx

Comment: FSharpValue.GetUnionFields is used to get the value of the Union. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!